# Android NDK/JNI: is malloc global (static char*) variable without free ok?

Tags: android, memory, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have an android app which has some JNI methods.
Each of these methods works with java reflections mostly and for that I need to have some strings (names of java methods/classes/etc - they are not constants in my case).
So I want to do some JNI initialization work which will prepare these strings before calling these JNI methods from java - I allocate (using malloc) global string variables (static char*) which will be used inside these methods whenever they called.

What is the best way to allocate/deallocate such global variables?
I could do constants but I need to modify their values at runtime (during initialization)

Right now I have initialization method which I call from Application.onCreate() - it allocates like 50 of string variables (static char*) and assigns them.
But I never call free().

Will there be any problem with this approach?
For example, when the app is killed by system, will there be any memory leak or corruption?
What if my app is started again (onCreate() called and variables are re-initialized again?)
I have not seen such problems myself, but memory is such a thing... maybe its just my luck :)

I thought of doing initialization in JNI_OnLoad, but again - when to free the resources?

Comment: If the process dies or is killed, all its memory is released.  But if another onCreate() *in an existing process* will cause you to re-allocate these items without releasing the old ones, then that is a memory leak you should fix.  Either treat them as singletons, allocate them statically in the source (rather than with malloc()) or free them when done.

Comment: and if the memory leaks - what could happen in worst case? app crashes?

Comment: If the leak is big enough, other apps will start being killed off to make room for yours, which starts to bog the system down if the user is using multiple apps.  If your app grows big enough, it will be killed as soon as the user switches away from it.  At some point the device will run out of memory and your app will just be killed, though the system tries very hard to not kill the foreground app.  Even if the leaks are minor, it's useful to figure out how to avoid them, so that when you're designing future components where it will matter more you automatically do the right thing.